# Not able to access value from .env file in strapi database.js file

Tags: node.js, docker, containers, strapi, dotenv

I am dockerizing a strapi application with mongodb atlas hosted database. The image is working fine when I am hardcoding the database credentials inside config/database.js file. But I want to get those credentials from .env file. According to strapi doc I can get those variable in database.js file without using the dotenv package

https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations.html#environment-variables

But this shows me the following error

> error Error connecting to the Mongo database. URI does not have
> hostname, domain name and tld

I tried to use dotenv and used process.env to get variables but it still shows me the same erro. Any idea how can I resolve this?

database connection code

```
require('dotenv').config()
const {
  DATABASE_HOST,
  DATABASE_USERNAME,
  DATABASE_PASSWORD
} = process.env;

module.exports = ({ env }) =>
  ({
    defaultConnection: 'default',
    connections: {
      default: {
        connector: 'mongoose',
        settings: {
          host: env('DATABASE_HOST', 'open-jade-cms-0.r07jc.mongodb.net'),
          srv: env.bool('DATABASE_SRV', true),
          port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT', 27017),
          database: env('DATABASE_NAME', 'open-jade-cms-dev'),
          username: env('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'open-jade-data-admin'),
          password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'uppERH7xmydTpXI8')
        },
        options: {
          authenticationDatabase: env('AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE', null),
          ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', true),
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

docker file

```
FROM strapi/base

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm install dotenv

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm","run", "start:develop"]
```

Comment: can you please show your Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

Comment: sure. this is just docker file. here is

FROM strapi/base

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm install dotenv

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm","run", "start:develop"]

Comment: can you post docker-compose file too in your question?

Comment: done, please check

Comment: I dont have compose file, just usinf docker file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need to install `dotenv` package. Just make sure you have `.env` in place. Something like this:

```sh
DATABASE_CLIENT=mongo
DATABASE_NAME=strapi
DATABASE_HOST=mongoexample
DATABASE_PORT=27017
DATABASE_USERNAME=strapi
DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=strapi
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

It is a good idea to use docker-compose when running strapi locally

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  strapiexample:
    image: strapi/strapi
    container_name: strapiexample
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: ${DATABASE_CLIENT}
      DATABASE_NAME: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      DATABASE_HOST: ${DATABASE_HOST}
      DATABASE_PORT: ${DATABASE_PORT}
      DATABASE_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - strapi-app-network
    volumes:
      - ./app:/srv/app
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
```

The above has been taken from [strapi blogs](https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-run-a-strapi-dev-stack-with-docker-compose)